# Graph of $S_n$ with respect to transposition

Tags: graph-theory, permutations

Consider the graph $G_n$, with $V(G_n) = S_n$ (the set of permutations of a set of size $n$) and having an edge $\sigma\sigma'$ iif $\sigma'$ can be obtained from $\sigma$ by applying a transposition.

This $G_n$, defined that way, has a "name"?

It seems pretty easy, (and this is the **main question**) but I'm not sure how $G_n$ "looks like". For instante:

- $G_1$ is $K_1$
- $G_2$ is $K_2$
- $G_3$ is $K_{3,3}$
- $G_4$ is **??**
- $\dots$
- $G_n$ is **??**

Comment: It's the Cayley graph of $S_n$ with respect to the set of transpositions. Not sure if there is a more concrete name...

Comment: Well, but is it easy to see how $G_4$ looks like?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking?

Comment: I'm asking what should be the "??" in my original question. The graph described when $n = 3$ is the $K_{3,3}$. I wonder what's the graph described on, for instance $n=4$. I'm looking for an answer like $G_4 = K_{8,8,8}$, which is wrong althought $K_{8,8,8}$ has 24 vertices, as expected.

Comment: For instance, $G_4$ can not be a complete $n$ partite graph, like the previous cases, since there must be two vertices in $G_4$ with distance $3$, right?

Comment: The graph $G_n$ is the Hasse diagram of the absolute order on $S_n$. This gives some insight into what this graph "looks like." See http://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1405v2.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

This is the undirected version of the *Bruhat graph*.  To make the graph directed, direct an edge $\sigma \rightarrow \sigma'$ if $\ell(\sigma') > \ell(\sigma)$, where $\ell(\sigma)$ denotes the *length* of $\sigma$ defined to be the number of inversions of $\sigma$.  A related graph is the Hasse diagram of the Bruhat order, which is the subgraph of the Bruhat graph where only the edges $\sigma \rightarrow \sigma'$ with $\ell(\sigma') = \ell(\sigma) + 1$ are kept.  A basic fact is that for any edge $\sigma \rightarrow \sigma'$ in the Bruhat graph with $\ell(\sigma') - \ell(\sigma) > 1$, there is a path of edges in the Hasse diagram starting at $\sigma$ and ending at $\sigma'$.

A standard reference for this material is Chapter 2 of Bjorner and Brenti's *Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups*.

Comment: Not precisely, because he allows any transpositions, not just $\left(i,i+1\right)$.

Comment: @darij grinberg:  Only using simple transpositions defines the weak order on S_n, while using all transpositions defines the Bruhat order.

Answer (score 2):

1) One can say something about the  $k$-neighbourhoods  of a vertex $v$ (i.e. sets of vertices at distance $k$ from $v$). For $v=()$, the identity element of $S_n$, each $k$-neighbourhood is a union of conjugacy classes of $S_n$.

E.g. for $k=1$ you get  $n \choose 2$ vertices, corresponding to involutions of type $2^1$, a.k.a. transpositions $(ab)$, and there are no edges between them. That is, there are no triangles in your graph. By the way this immediately tells you that $K_{888}$ for $G_4$ is very far off.

For $k=2$ you get two types of vertices, namely, the ones corresponding to involutions of type $2^2$, i.e. $(ab)(cd)$, and the ones corresponding to $3$-cycles $(abc)$. This will tell you that for any two vertices at distance 2 there is unique 4-cycle which contains them.
Indeed, you can get $(ab)(cd)$ using two transpositions either as $(ab)\cdot (cd)$ or as $(cd)\cdot (ab)$, and you can get $(abc)$ either as $(ac)\cdot (bc)$ or as $(bc)\cdot (ab)$.

2) Another interesting and sometimes useful fact is that the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix $A$ of $G_n$ can be computed from the values of the irreducible characters of $S_n$; namely, $A$ can be viewed as an element $\sum\limits_{\pi \text{ a transposition}}\pi$ in the center of the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$, and the center is generated by such conjugacy class sums; this allows you to simultaneously diagnonalise them, etc.